# Mutex locked confusion

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, std, mutex

Hello i am confused about mutex locked. I have a question for experienced people about multithreading. For example in my code i have class that hold mutex and condition variable, i used these for socket communication. I used `mutex.lock()`for lock function's variables but i could not understood what i locked. did i lock function's variables or another things.
I used `unique_lock` because i want to use `condition_variable` and lock function's variables but i dont know if it works. I want to create sender and receiver that wait for eachother.

My Receive data function

```
void connect_tcp::Recv_data(SOCKET s,mms_response &response,Signals *signals,bool &ok,ıvır_zıvır &ıvır) {
    LinkedList** list = new LinkedList * [1000];
    uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t [10000];
    //ok = false;
    unique_lock <mutex> lck(ıvır.mutex);
    if (ıvır.for_data == true) {
        dataready = true;
    }
    ıvır.cv.wait(lck, [] {return dataready; });
    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    recv(s, (char*)buffer, 10000, 0);
    dataready = false;
    decode_bytes(response,buffer, list,signals);
    ok = true;
    ıvır.ıvır_control--;

}
```

My Send data function

```
int connect_tcp::send_data(SOCKET s, mms_response &response,LinkedList** list,int &j,bool &ok, ıvır_zıvır& ıvır) {
    /*this_thread::sleep_for(0.3s);*/
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    ıvır.mutex.lock();
    uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[10000];
    while (i<j)
    {
        for (auto it = list[i]->data.begin(); it != list[i]->data.end(); it++)
        {
            buffer[k]=*it;
            k++;

        }
        i++;

    }

    int jk = 0;

        jk= send(s, (const char*)buffer, list[0]->size, 0);
        cout << jk << " Bytes sent" << endl;

        dataready = true;
        this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        ıvır.mutex.unlock();
        ıvır.cv.notify_one();

    if (jk == -1) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i<j) {
        delete list[i]; 
        i++;
    }
    j = 1;
    return jk;
}
```

I read a lot of books and entries but no one explain that `mutex.lock()` what is locking. I saw only one explain that is " if 2 thread want to use same source `mutex.lock` is blocked that such as `stdin` and `stdout`" .

Comment: It locks the mutex, the mutex has no relationship with any other variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mutex is a thing that only one thread can have at a time. If no thread touches a particular variable unless it has a particular mutex, then we say that mutex locks that thing.

Mutexes are generally used to prevent more than one thread from touching something at the same time. It is up to the programmer to associated particular mutexes with particular shared resources by ensuring that shared resources aren't looked at or touched except by threads that hold the applicable mutexes.

Generally speaking, you don't want to do anything "heavy" while holding a mutex unless you have no choice. In particular, calling `sleep_for` is particularly foolish and bad. Ditto for `recv`.

Comment: so if we have 2 thread that use Recv_data function and when first thread is at inside of recv_data function ,if other thread try to pass recv_data function ,other cannot the other thread pass or wait ?

Comment: @SerhanErkovan That depends on what those functions are doing. If, for example, the two threads would each try to receive on the same socket, you'd have a huge problem. If they're handling different sockets, no problem at all. But usually you don't need a mutex to stop two threads from trying to do the very same thing, you need mutexes to stop two threads from doing different things with/to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

> did i lock function's variables or another things.

Just to be absolutely clear about it:  If thread A keeps some mutex M locked, that does *not* prevent other threads from doing *anything* except locking the same mutex M at the same time.

If somebody says that "Mutex M protects variables x, y, and z," that's just a shorthand way of saying that the program has been carefully written so that every thread always locks mutex M before it accesses any of those variables.

Other answers here go into more detail about that...

Answer (score 0):

from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)

`The mutex class is a synchronization primitive that can be used to protect shared data from being simultaneously accessed by multiple threads.`

and as the name suggests, a mutex is a mutual exclusion state holder that can expose a single state (lock state) between threads in an atomic way. Locking is implemented through different mechanisms such as unique_lock, shared_lock etc.

On a different note: your code has a couple of issues:

1. The first two lines In Recv_data function (allocations) are going to leak, after the function returns. take a look at [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) on how to initialize and allocate in modern c++
2. Since you are using thread locks and mutex there is no need for condition variables. the mutex will guarantee the mutual exclusion of threads, and there is no need to notify. However, this depends strongly on the way you spawn threads.
3. You are mixing two concepts, socket communication, and threads. This seems a bit fishy. That is, it is not clear from which context your functions are being called(different processes? in which case there is no point in talking about threads).

I'd suggest you simplify your code for sending and receiving a single variable (instead of arrays) to understand the basics first and then move on to more complex use cases.